# How do I avoid this ValueError?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a working bit of code equivalent to

```
def foo(x):
    if (df.A == 0 or df.B > df.C):
        return 0
    else:
        return (*some stuff*)

df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x),axis=1)
```

Of course

```
_.apply(...,axis=1)_
```

is horribly slow and I want to do it efficiently. I tried the following:

```
crit = (df.A != 0 and df.B <= df.C) #this is just the negation of the previous boolean
df['D'] = 0 
df.loc[crit,'D'] = (*some stuff*)
```

Here, I get an error:

```
_ValueError_, _the truth value of a Series is ambiguous_
```

If my *crit* only has one clause, it works fine, however. What am I missing here, and how do I fix it? I must confess I find it hard to grok how pandas does these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '&' instead of 'and'. This has been explained in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
crit = ((df.A != 0) & (df.B <= df.C))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Set a default value for your `D` column, then replace that value for rows that matches your query.

```
some_default_value = -1
df["D"] = some_default_value
df.loc[(df.A == 0) | (df.B > df.C), "D"] = 0
```